# Tell any UITextField to dismiss

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield, first-responder

How can I tell the current `firstResponder` to `resign`? I have a `UITableView` with a bunch of `TextFields` and I don't know which is active at all times. I thought about storing pointers to all cells in an array and iterating through it, telling every cell to `resignFirstResponder` but I'm sure there is an easier way. Maybe something like `[CurrentFirstResponder resignFirstResponder]`?

I would appreciate some help, Fabian

**EDIT**: I don't want to dismiss the keyboard when the user taps done. It should be dismissed programmatically. Since I don't know which `UITextField` is active at any time, I am searching for something that calls `resignFirstResponder` on the current `FirstResponder`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could keep a reference to the UITextfeild that's actively editing using `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` on the [UITextFieldDelegate Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) or you could do this with your parent view:

```
UIView * myParentViewView;//view containing one or more editable UI controls 
[myParentViewView endEditing:YES];
```

Comment: Figured that out just now too :) The problem was that my `UITextField` s are enclosed in custom `UITableViewCell` s, but I added a new delegate method that sends `- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)tf` to the delegate. There I then have an instance variable...

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will solve your problem,

Assign delegate to UItextField,

```
textField.delegate=self;
```

then in following method

```
    - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {
//This for to resign on begin editing
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }

 - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {
//This for to resign on end editing
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
```

If you dont want to the textField to be editable then,

```
textField.editing=NO;
```

Set tag to distingush your textFields

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the UITextFieldDelegate ([reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html)). Whenever `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField` is called, perform `[textField resignFirstResponder]`, since this method is always invoked with the currently active textfield. 
If you still need to distinguish between your textfields, try setting a tag and use it with `if(textfield.tag == self.mytextfield.tag) {...}`